# Can you surf to a site that has shared hosting with ipadress?

Tags: dns, ip, hosts-file

Is it possible to surf to a site that has shared hosting on the web hotel with the ipadress?

Can you change the hosts file in any way?

Comment: Has it got a dedicated IP address?

Comment: No it shares Ip with several other sites. Shared hosting. If you ping the www.site.domain You get an IP which takes you the the webhotel.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if they all share the same ip then they cannot be accessed in this way.

Comment: Hmm ok mmm thought so but everything seems to be done with these 1 and 0s ...

Comment: @ohope5 No, you can: It's called virtual hosts, at least by Apache.

Comment: @ohope5 You are correct in almost all cases. However HTTP is the exception to the rule.

Comment: @Hennes I am aware of this, but i though that was only domain names, I may have confused the question then, I though is was asking about typing just the ip into browser bar, not the whole domain name.

Comment: The OP will need to use DynDNS to get a host name or a domain name. It is a workaround, but it is possible and might work just fine for home users. If this was posted on [SF] I would have said "possible, but just do not do it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depend in precisely what you mean with "hared hosting on the web hotel with the IP adress?"

For most programs it is only possible to use a single IP:port_nummer combination. HTTP is an exeption to this since the desired host is mentioned in the HTTP requests.

Thus it is possible to have a single IP (either shared or dynamic) with several host/domain names pointing to that same IP, and use it to serve different webpages depending on the URL you enter in the browser.

However there still still only be a single web-server running at IP:port_nummer, which means that you will have to coordinate the person running that web-server. YOu can find more information on this if you search on the keyword [virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting).

Comment: I see. I would have to get the portnumber from the Web Hotel and then let the Web Hotel allow me to surf through the FW to this portnumber?

Comment: Not quite. If there is no web server running yet then you can just install one (or ask your shared provider admin to install one). Then you and you alone can serve webpages from that computer.  However since that would block anyone else from hosting webpages on that shared computer they are not likely to comply. Instead they probably want to install a web-server, enable the virtual hosts options and redirect all web requests to a per-user folder. That way each user can have their own website in a separate place.

Comment: For this to work each user will either need to use the same host name (e.g. http://test.myprovider.tld/different_folder_per user/ ) or a user will need their own domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can with just one IP Address. You can run an Apache Reverse Proxy Server and use DYNDNS with different subdomain names to point to your server's IP Address. This would avoid you having to register your own domain name. You can then tell it to route to a different VirtualHost based on the subdomain name and/or domain name.

This all assumes that you have root access to the server. This can also be done with a Virtual Server which now-a-days is as cheap as a shared host. Check out www.digitalocean.com and www.alienvps.com

See my answer in this question. [Multiple web servers behind a single firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/596115/multiple-web-servers-behind-a-single-firewall/596124#596124)

Comment: +1 for "This all assumes that you have root access to the server. ".  @OP. We really can use more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to surf it as a user, and there is Apache running, you can simply change your hosts file (depends on OS you use) and set it like `ip_address site.domain`
So when you type the url in your browser, you'll get access to it, since your system will know the IP address (so it won't ask DNS for it), and their Apache will know which site you want to access