# One public IP and multiple VPS servers?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, dns

I have one public IP address that I want to share with multiple servers

Desired solution would be something like this:
when I send a request to sv1.domain.tld the request will be forwarded to 1.0.0.100
when I send a request to sv2.domain.tld the request will be forwarded to 10.0.0.101
etc

I want to forward all ports for the host so if I want to connect via ssh with sv1.domain.tld, the request will go to 10.0.0.100

I have tried to do that with bind9, but no luck

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve this problem with a DNS server, you need to setup a gateway
computer with a
[Reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

The router will route all incoming requests on port 80 to the same gateway
computer. That computer will farm those requests out to other machines on the network to do the actual processing work.

You may use for that Apache with multiple named vhosts and mod_rewrite,
or straight mod_proxy with ProxyPass directives
([example](https://superuser.com/questions/596115/multiple-web-servers-behind-a-single-firewall)),
or more sophisticated setups using Squid or nginx or other.

Comment: will the mod_proxy work with all ports? I'm looking for solution that allow me to connect to specify server using its hostname

Comment: That's the function of a reverse proxy, but setting it up will need some study.

Comment: @Lucas: no, this does not work with all protocols as it requires support in the protocol. HTTP does this (in the "Hostname" header), SSH does not support it.